# Preventing `\mainmatter` from inserting a blank page

Tags: blank-page

`\mainmatter` seems to sometimes force a blank page if the current contents (the place where `\mainmatter` is called) are on an odd numbered page. `openany` and `oneside` do not seem to work here. They only work when opening a new chapter, but not when the main matter starts.

I want to disable inserting of blank pages altogether even at the beginning of the main matter.

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany, oneside]{book}

    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \geometry{twoside=false, showframe=false,inner=1.05in,outer=1.05in,includemp=true,asymmetric=true,bindingoffset=0mm,marginparsep=0mm, marginparwidth=0mm}
    \geometry{bottom=0.9in,vmarginratio=3:5,includehead=true, includefoot=true,headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt,footskip=10.9mm}

% END_FOLD

    \usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\blindtext

\mainmatter
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does the `asymetric` option do for you? Why are you including all those different options to `geometry`? In other words, why do you tell the package you do not want a `twoside` document, and later overwrite that stating you *do want* `twoside`?

Comment: I copied the code from my thesis .tex file. I was just trying to fine-tune the geometry in such a way that the blank page will exist.

Comment: Are the empty pages even-numbered?

Comment: @Mico. Yes, it seems that `asymetric=false` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a temporarily altered definition of `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany, oneside]{book}

    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD

    \geometry{twoside=false, showframe=false,inner=1.05in,outer=1.05in,includemp=true,asymmetric=true,bindingoffset=0mm,marginparsep=0mm, marginparwidth=0mm}
    \geometry{bottom=0.9in,vmarginratio=3:5,includehead=true, includefoot=true,headheight=8pt, headsep=14pt,footskip=10.9mm}

% END_FOLD

    \usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\blindtext

{
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\newpage}
\mainmatter
}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the geometry option "asymmetric" or "asymmetric = true" are a special alternative to option `twooside`. Therefore your settings will lead to a twosided document. `\ mainmatter` changes the page numbering system and restarts the page counter. The blank even page before "\ manimatter" is inserted to ensure that right-hand pages receive odd page numbers. Do not try to get an odd page number on a left-hand page in a twosided document. So do not redefine `\cleardoublepage`. Note that in a onesided document there will be no blank page before `\mainmatter`.

Comment: In my case (in a memoir document), this made me completely lose the effect of mainmatter. In particular, chapters stopped being numbered.