# Grouping mainmatter prevents chapter count

Tags: grouping

When I [group my mainmatter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498201/preventing-mainmatter-from-inserting-a-blank-page) to prevent it of inserting a blank page, my chapter numbering dissapears as well.

I can't seem to find any work-around or even why this is happening.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,twocolumn,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \tableofcontents

  {
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\newpage}
    \mainmatter
  }
  \chapter{Two columns}
  \lipsum[1-5]

  \chapter{Two columns again, but it's not}
  \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

The moment I remove the curly braces, it starts working again.

Comment: The grouping here voids your `\renewcommand` and whatever `\mainmatter` does. What is it that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I used this to remove a blank page when the front matter has an odd number of pages.

I followed the instructions of the linked answer.

When looking at the document classes, I think 'report' fits better for my use case, as it does not have the frontmatter, mainmatter and backmatter

Comment: as the comment under the answer you referenced indicates, that is a bad example to follow,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store whatever `\cleardoublepage` does and restore it after calling `\mainmatter`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,openany]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\let\oldcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{\newpage}
\mainmatter
\let\cleardoublepage\oldcleardoublepage

\chapter{Two columns}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Two columns again}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does solve my problem. Another solution to achieve what I needed was to remove the 'twoside' option or change from 'book' to report.